# Not able to compare day in momentjs with isSame()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs, date

Looking solution to alert when today is the birthday. Here comparing **Day** and **Month** in `isSame()` Very unfortunately the `isSame()` not comparing day with given date. Also not getting true for **month** when year is different.

Looking for javascript to find user's birth day

```js
const dateOfBirth = moment("2018-09-07T13:36:14.000Z").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
const today = moment(new Date()).format("DD-MM-YYYY");

if (
  moment(dateOfBirth).isSame(today, "day") &&
  moment(dateOfBirth).isSame(today, "month")
) {
  console.log("Today is your birth day");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using a UTC timestamp when you just want to compare dates means that the comparison may fail when it shouldn't. Trim the time part and just use the date: `moment('2018-09-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` then, as Webber says, set the year to the current year and compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Momentjs has an [api](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) to check whether or not a certain date is the same.

As arguments it takes the date object, instead of the formatted strings.

In order to check for any year, just use a trick: set the year of the object to todays year.

Example:

```js
// Date in any year
const dateOfBirth = moment("2018-09-07T13:36:14.000Z");

// Set year to current year
dateOfBirth.year(moment().year());

// Compare to today
console.log('Is it your birthday?', dateOfBirth.isSame(new Date(), "day"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

It is also possible to make a copy of the variable, so that the original can stay the same.